# Google chart : How to make differential timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a script to display a timechart with Google Chart, however I can't manage to modify it in order to display a differential chart.

I would simply be able to calculate the difference between my two values and display it, instead of the total.
I have [12, 3000, 2500],  [15, 4700, 5800]
First value is the time, then second value is team X and third value team Y. I would like to display :

- at time 12 that team X has 500 more than team X.
- at time 15 that team Y has 1100 more than team X.

Thanks a lot,
Tim

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

function drawLineColors() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Blue Team');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Red Team');
   
      data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 0],     [3, 1700, 1600],   [6, 1800, 1700],    [9, 2500, 2423], 
        [12, 3000, 2500],  [15, 4700, 5800], 
        [18, 5200, 5900],  [21, 5500, 6000], 
        [24, 6000, 6200],  [27, 6800, 6700], 
        [30, 7500, 7000],  [33, 7800, 8200],
        [36, 7900, 9756],  [39, 8000, 10752], 
        [42, 9000, 13753],  [45, 15000, 17845],
  [48, 19000, 13753],  [55, 25000, 17845]
      ]);

      var options = {
     
      lineWidth: 5,
       animation:{
          duration: 5000,
          easing: 'in',
          startup : true
       },
        legend : {
         position : 'top'
        },
        //fontName : 'Shentox 7',
        enableInteractivity:false,
        width: 712,
       height: 156,
        backgroundColor : {fill:'transparent'},
        curveType: 'function',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Team Gold'
        },
        chartArea:{width:'72px',height:'126px'},
        colors: ['#FF0000', '#0000FF']
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for the mistake, updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `DataView.setColumns` to provide a formula for column values

then use the `DataView` to draw the `chart`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

function drawLineColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue Team');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red Team');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0], [3, 1700, 1600],
    [6, 1800, 1700], [9, 2500, 2423],
    [12, 3000, 2500], [15, 4700, 5800],
    [18, 5200, 5900], [21, 5500, 6000],
    [24, 6000, 6200], [27, 6800, 6700],
    [30, 7500, 7000], [33, 7800, 8200],
    [36, 7900, 9756], [39, 8000, 10752],
    [42, 9000, 13753], [45, 15000, 17845],
    [48, 19000, 13753], [55, 25000, 17845]
  ]);

  var options = {
    lineWidth: 5,
    animation:{
      duration: 5000,
      easing: 'in',
      startup : true
    },
    legend : {
      position : 'top'
    },
    enableInteractivity:false,
    width: 712,
    height: 156,
    backgroundColor : {fill:'transparent'},
    curveType: 'function',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Team Gold'
    },
    chartArea:{width:'72px',height:'126px'},
    colors: ['#FF0000', '#0000FF']
  };

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  dataView.setColumns([0, {
    calc: function (data, row) {
      return data.getValue(row, 2) - data.getValue(row, 1);
    },
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Variance'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataView, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: That's perfect for my question, however now I have that I changed to AreaChart to be more understandable and I would like to be able to change the color or the background and the line for negative values, maybe I should open another question, i'll try first :)